# Nginx return file for path

Tags: nginx

I want Nginx to return r.json file for path example.com/r/
What I tried:

```
location /r/ {
    alias /home/user/media/json/r.json;
}
```

But all that didn't work. I've got 500 with message:

/home/user/media/json/r.jsonindex.html is not a directory

Comment: strange, it worked for me

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `index` directive to name `r.json` as the default filename within that location:

```
location /r/ {
    index r.json;
    alias /home/user/media/json/;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. One more question. How can I make a rewrite to another location if r.json does not exist? Not to another file, but location, served by gunicorn

Comment: @shaihulud As an alternative to `index`, you could use `try_files $uri $uri/r.json /another/url;` See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: @Ivan the OP already tried that - it's in their question! However, `alias` should contain the full path to the file when used with a regular expression `location` statement. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Answer (score 11):

```
  location = /r/ {
    try_files r.json =404;
  }
```

Comment: the simplest solution among the others; this works for `location = /` as well

Comment: This approach seems sensible but did not work for me at all in nginx 1.20.2

Comment: I have to add a slash before the file name, like `try_files /r.json =404;`, otherwise Nginx returns 404.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to add a `Content-Disposition` header to show the file name while downloading it from browser:

```
location /r/ {
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=r.json";
    index r.json;
    alias /home/user/media/json/;
}
```