# Nginx can't find file

Tags: nginx

I have simple nginx server configuration which works and looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  location /cert {
    alias /aaa.txt;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

Proxy pass works like it should do but what doesn't work is getting this `/aaa.txt` file.

I tried changing `alias...` into:

- `return 200 'Hi'` - This indeed return and download file named `Hi`
- `root /` > As I read, `root` just adds to link before so it is not suitable for this situation but tried it
- `try_files /aaa.txt =404` - Not working

I tried changing permission of `/aaa.txt` with command `chown www-data:www-data aaa.txt` and still not working.

I have tried creating folder `/wwwroot/` and put it inside that folder and do everything the same but still not working.

I do not know what else to try.

Pointing to answers provided in suggested question [Nginx return file for path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317540/nginx-return-file-for-path) I edited my setup file and (this time I put it in folder `wwwroot`) and it is still not working

```
GNU nano 6.2        /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy                  
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  location /cert {
    index aaa.txt;
    alias /wwwroot;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx return file for path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317540/nginx-return-file-for-path)

Comment: @Mate it is still not working. I can't get idea why. Proxy_pass work normally, but this is not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was quite simple. I was all time putting path relative to `~` which is not where nginx starts. In terminal you see it as `~` but its full path is `/home/[user]/` so when i created folder `wwwroot` it was not located at `/wwwroot` but `/home/ubuntu/wwwroot` and that is the reason why it coulnd't find it.